# Plot a line over a bar chart from a data table

Tags: line, bar

i have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\bein{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
 calculate offset/.code={
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{(\pgfplotspointmeta *10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)*\pgfplots@y@veclength)}
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
 },
 every node near coord/.style={
 /pgfplots/calculate offset,
 yshift=-\testmacro
 }
}
\pgfplotstableread{
1 829 794 552 401
2 1011 1104 843 620
3 658 755 546 428
}\dataset
\pgfplotstableread{
1 425 404 319 227
2 511 575 411 341
3 327 386 298 211
}\correct
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
 bar width=10pt,
 enlarge x limits={abs=0.9},
 width=12cm,
 height=6cm,
 ymin=0,
 ymax=1200, 
 ylabel={Frequency},
 xtick=data,
 xticklabels = {
 Gating1,
 Gating2,
 Gating3,
 },
 xlabel=Stimuli Condition,
 xticklabel style={yshift=-10ex},
 major x tick style = {opacity=0},
 minor x tick num = 1,
 minor tick length=1ex,
 every node near coord/.append style={
 anchor=east,
 rotate=90
 }
 ]
\addplot[draw=black,fill=blue!20, nodes near coords=Active] table[x index=0,y index=1] \dataset;
\addplot[draw=black,fill=red!20, nodes near coords=Interactive] table[x index=0,y index=2] \dataset;
\addplot[draw=black,fill=green!20, nodes near coords=Passive] table[x index=0,y index=3] \dataset;
\addplot[draw=black,fill=yellow!20, nodes near coords=None] table[x index=0,y index=4] \dataset;
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
[ybar,
 enlarge x limits={abs=0.9},
 width=12cm,
 height=6cm,
 ymin=0,
 ymax=1200, 
 xtick=data,
 xticklabels = {
 },
 ]
\addplot[draw=blue,ultra thick,only marks,mark=-,mark size=25pt] table[x index=0,y index=1] \correct;
\addplot[draw=blue,ultra thick,only marks,mark=-,mark size=25pt] table[x index=0,y index=2] \correct;
\addplot[draw=blue,ultra thick,only marks,mark=-,mark size=25pt] table[x index=0,y index=3] \correct;
\addplot[draw=blue,ultra thick,only marks,mark=-,mark size=25pt] table[x index=0,y index=4] \correct;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Frequency and Proportion of Statement Responses by Stimuli Type and Gating Condition}\label{Statements}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the bar part alone is perfect, with the colours, and spacing etc. I am having problems with adding in the lines. The second data frame, 'correct', should sit over the bars, and be a plotted line with curves. Instead it sits to the right, as an extra set of data on the graph, and gives horizontal lines. I want to end up with something like this, with the lines over the bars, but hopefully with a smoother line.[image]

[image]

Comment: Please complete your code fragment to a small document, which we can compile as it is.

Comment: I actually managed part of it, I put the lines over the bars but they are still horizontal, and not a plot. I have update the code in the original question

Comment: The updated code does not work, e.g. `\bein{document}` is wrong, but if one fixes this, there are still errors.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, check `\addplot`s, one is without backslash ... now i haven't time for anything more :-(

Comment: thanks, i wondered where the 4th line was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
 calculate offset/.code={
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{(\pgfplotspointmeta *10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)*\pgfplots@y@veclength)}
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
 },
 every node near coord/.style={
 /pgfplots/calculate offset,
 yshift=-\testmacro
 }
}
\pgfplotstableread{
1 829 794 552 401
2 1011 1104 843 620
3 658 755 546 428
}\dataset
\pgfplotstableread{
1 425 404 319 227
2 511 575 411 341
3 327 386 298 211
}\correct

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
 bar width=10pt,
 enlarge x limits={abs=0.9},
 width=12cm,
 height=6cm,
 ymin=0,
 ymax=1200, 
 ylabel={Frequency},
 xtick=data,
 xticklabels = {
 Gating1,
 Gating2,
 Gating3,
 },
 xticklabel style={yshift=-10ex},
 xlabel=Stimuli Condition,
 xlabel style={yshift=-10ex},
 major x tick style = {opacity=0},
 minor x tick num = 1,
 minor tick length=1ex,
 every node near coord/.append style={
 anchor=east,
 rotate=90
 }
 ]
\addplot[draw=black,fill=blue!20, nodes near coords=Active] table[x index=0,y index=1] \dataset;
\addplot[draw=black,fill=red!20, nodes near coords=Interactive] table[x index=0,y index=2] \dataset;
\addplot[draw=black,fill=green!20, nodes near coords=Passive] table[x index=0,y index=3] \dataset;
\addplot[draw=black,fill=yellow!20, nodes near coords=None] table[x index=0,y index=4] \dataset;
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
[enlarge x limits={abs=0.9},
 width=12cm,
 height=6cm,
 ymin=0,
 ymax=1200, 
 xtick=data,
 xticklabels = {
 },
 ]
\addplot[draw=blue,ultra thick, xshift=-18pt] table[x index=0,y index=1] \correct;
\addplot[draw=red,ultra thick,xshift=-6pt] table[x index=0,y index=2] \correct;
\addplot[draw=green,ultra thick,xshift=6pt] table[x index=0,y index=3] \correct;
\addplot[draw=yellow,ultra thick,xshift=18pt] table[x index=0,y index=4] \correct;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Revised solution using `\pgfplotstabletranspose`.  I store the starting points using coordinates (A) through (C).  The xshift centers the data points on the bars, and the xscale was a WAG.  I've tried computing the scale factor with no success.

[image: demo2]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\newlength{\tempdima}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
 calculate offset/.code={
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{(\pgfplotspointmeta *10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)*\pgfplots@y@veclength)}
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
 },
 every node near coord/.style={
 /pgfplots/calculate offset,
 yshift=-\testmacro
 }
}
\pgfplotstableread{
1 829 794 552 401
2 1011 1104 843 620
3 658 755 546 428
}\dataset
\pgfplotstableread{
1 425 404 319 227
2 511 575 411 341
3 327 386 298 211
}\correct
%\pgfplotstabletypeset{\correct}
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=0]{\transpose}{\correct}%
%\pgfplotstabletypeset{\transpose}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
 bar width=10pt,
 enlarge x limits={abs=0.9},
 width=12cm,
 height=6cm,
 ymin=0,
 ymax=1200, 
 ylabel={Frequency},
 xtick=data,
 xticklabels = {
 Gating1,
 Gating2,
 Gating3,
 },
 xticklabel style={yshift=-10ex},
 xlabel=Stimuli Condition,
 xlabel style={yshift=-10ex},
 major x tick style = {opacity=0},
 minor x tick num = 1,
 minor tick length=1ex,
 every node near coord/.append style={
 anchor=east,
 rotate=90
 }
 ]
\addplot[draw=black,fill=blue!20, nodes near coords=Active] table[x index=0,y index=1] \dataset;
\addplot[draw=black,fill=red!20, nodes near coords=Interactive] table[x index=0,y index=2] \dataset;
\addplot[draw=black,fill=green!20, nodes near coords=Passive] table[x index=0,y index=3] \dataset;
\addplot[draw=black,fill=yellow!20, nodes near coords=None] table[x index=0,y index=4] \dataset;
\coordinate (A) at (axis cs: 0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (axis cs: 1,0);
\coordinate (C) at (axis cs: 2,0);
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
[enlarge x limits={abs=0.9},
 width=12cm,
 height=6cm,
 ymin=0,
 ymax=1200, 
 hide axis
 ]
\addplot[draw=black,ultra thick,shift=(A),xshift=4pt,xscale=0.2] table[x index=0,y index=1] \transpose;
\addplot[draw=black,ultra thick,shift=(B),xshift=4pt,xscale=0.2] table[x index=0,y index=2] \transpose;
\addplot[draw=black,ultra thick,shift=(C),xshift=4pt,xscale=0.2] table[x index=0,y index=3] \transpose;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: almost but not quite, I wanted just 3 lines, one per group of bars, not connecting the graphs, but thankyou for the code, I will try to amend it later when I work on the project again. I can probably correct it by rearranging the data table. Thanks so much for showing me how not to just have horizontal lines.

Comment: I can't make it work. I need the first part, the bars, to go across the groups, and the line to stay within the groups. Do you know how I can specify the gating condition in the code? I was just thinking to plot like {Gating1 {Active, 425} {Interactive, x} etc}. Is this possible? I didn't get a syntax to work.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: i've added a quick sketch the original question as it was hard to explain.

Comment: Thankyou so much! I was starting to wonder if it was possible!